# My Pineapple Open Tarts won't dislodge from their moulds

Tags: pineapple, tart

I am baking pineapple open tarts using individual aluminium moulds. I use shortcrust pastry. I have difficulty in dislodging them from their moulds when they are done? I tried to remove them as soon as they are out from the oven as well as after having left them to cool in their respective moulds. No difference, they just won't leave the moulds. The moulds were oiled with butter before use. What have I done wrong?

Comment: What type of molds are these? Do the bottoms lift out? Are they non-stick coated or just plain aluminum?

Comment: Did you butter them *and* dust with flour?  if yes: did you press the dough very hard into all nooks and crannies?

Answer (score 2):

If there is really no way to delicately take off the moulds, I'd suggest feezing them. Then once they've hardened, heat up the mould and try to push the tarts out/bang the mould on a hard (not fragile...) surface. They'll be hard enough so you can apply more force without breaking.

As a last resort... :)

Also, removing them right out of the oven might not be a great idea as they will often shrink while cooling down, which can help take them out. And as Fabby pointed out : butter AND flour.